# $in parameter in graphene-mongo queries

Tags: python, mongodb, graphene-python

I build mongodb queries and execute them like this:

```
query = '''query getArticles {
            articles_info(author_id: "ID1") {articles {
    id
    topic
    }
}'''
result = SCHEMA.execute(query)
```

Now I want to query articles with author_ids from a list. In mongodb, I do it like this: `{ author_id: { $in: ["ID1", "ID2"] } }`

I googled everywhere to find how this can be done in python all in vain. I tried these formats:

```
- author_id: { $in: ["ID1", "ID2"] }  
- author_id: { "$in": ["ID1", "ID2"] }  
- author_id__in: ["ID1", "ID2"]  
- author_id_in: ["ID1", "ID2"]  
- author_id_In: ["ID1", "ID2"]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you look into `nested dictionaries` in python?

Comment: I know nested dictionaries. How can I use them in this case?

Comment: `{ author_id: { $in: ["ID1", "ID2"] } }` is this not sufficient?

Comment: @Solen'ya this is the first thing I tried